# using javascript with zk

Tags: java, javascript, html, zk

I'm trying to use javascript in a *.zul

I have this script to create a list of objects(integers in this example, but it could be another type)

```
<zscript>
    <![CDATA[
        myList = new ArrayList();
        for(int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
            myList.add(i);

    ]]> 
</zscript>
```

I want to get the "myList" in this script, so I can do everything with this.

I tried to get it using getElementById method but it didn't work.

```
<script>
    var elmts=document.getElementById('myList');
        for(var i=0;i<elmts.length)
            alert(document.getElementById('id'+i).innerHTML);

</script>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is "myList" the name of an element in the HTML or the variable in the zscript tags?

Answer (score 0):

ZSCRIPT vaiables are available through EL expressions so you can get myList which is a List in Java by using `$[myList]` expression.

```
<zk>
  <zscript>
    <![CDATA[
    myList = new ArrayList();
    for(int i = 0;i < 2;i++)
        myList.add(i);

    ]]>
  </zscript>
  <script defer="true">
    var elmts = ${myList};
    for (var i =0,len=elmts.length; i != len; i++)
        alert(i);
  </script>
</zk>
```